# Query parameters without value for boolean

Tags: servicestack

Is there any way to make a query parameter without a value TRUE for a boolean in ServiceStack?

Example:

DTO has a field: `public bool IncludeOld { get; set; }`

Query parameter to set TRUE:
`...?includeOld=true` or `...?includeOld=1`

Would also like
`...?includeOld` to represent TRUE, which looks quite nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported. A query param without a value is considered to not have a value, it needs to be assigned a *truthy* value for it to be deserialized as **true**. Which for [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) includes:

- `true` or `True`
- `1`
- `t` or `T`
- `y` or `Y`
- `on`